# SELECT based on multiple fields in MS-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
  AcctNumb  |  PeriodEndingDate  |  WaterConsumption  |  ReadingType
```

There are multiple records for each AcctNumb, with the date that each record was recorded.

What I want to do is grab the most recent date, consumption reading, and reading type for each account.

I have tried using `MAX(PeriodEndingDate)` and `GROUP BY AcctNumb`, but I would need to aggregate all the other values, and none of the aggregate functions help me for the WaterConsumption, etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is a sample table

```
+----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+
| AcctNumb | PeriodEndingDate | WaterConsumption | ReadingType |
+----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+
|     1000 | 2018-03-31       |           122230 | A           |
|     1001 | 2018-03-31       |            24850 | A           |
|     1002 | 2018-03-31       |            88540 | A           |
|     1000 | 2017-12-31       |           123800 | A           |
|     1001 | 2017-12-31       |             3000 | E           |
+----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+
```

The ReadingType is whether it's an actual (A) reading, or an estimate (E).

Comment: Give some sample/dummy data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
  AcctNumb,
  PeriodEndingDate,
  WaterConsumption,
  ReadingType
FROM (SELECT
  AcctNumb,
  PeriodEndingDate,
  WaterConsumption,
  ReadingType,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNumb ORDER BY PeriodEndingDate DESC) AS MostrecentRecord
FROM <TableName>) dt
WHERE MostrecentRecord= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using ROW_NUMBER. It has been asked an answered thousands of times but the query is easier to write than find a duplicate.

```
select *
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by AcctNumb order by PeriodEndingDate)
    from YourTable
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DQ.* FROM
 (SELECT *, 
            Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNumb ORDER BY PeriodEndingDate DESC) AS RN    
              FROM YourTable 
  ) AS DQ 
  WHERE DQ.RN = 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.